# setting validator control's text from C# variable in aspx code?

Tags: asp.net

I have many asp.net validation controls in my aspx page and I dont want to hard code there error message.

I want to put a variable in C#, set error message there and set text properties of required filed validates. Unfortunately I dont know how to do it.

Please guide me is it possible and how it is possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ASP.Net Validation Control typically derives from [BaseValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fczazdzk), which has both a [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytkayke0) property as well as a [ErrorMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.errormessage) property.

You can set either of these in your code behind. So given this validator:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="myValidator"
   ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
   Display="Static"
   Width="100%" runat=server />
```

In your code behind you can do this:

```
var errorText = "Some Text";
var errorMessage = "It's broken yo!";

myValidator.Text = errorText;
myValidator.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
```

The Text property is what shows up directly in the control, and the ErrorMessage is what get's shown in the [ValidationSummary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary)

Comment: Josh I want to just set it by a variable not control by control for all controls. Is there a way ? can it be done like set text of a variable and set validation control's text property to it ? plz guide

Comment: @user576510 - I'm not completely sure I understand what you want at this point, but I've updated the answer to show how you could initialize the control properties from a variable.

Comment: Josh I meant to set the text from a C# variable but in aspx (code) page. plz advice